# Node Server - Source Code accessible

Tags: node.js, express

I noticed that when i navigate to `localhost:8080/server.js` (where my server.js is the server-expressjs obviously) the code of my server is shown in the browser!

Even, if i upload the application to openshift, i get the same result (you can test it):

```
http://tickets-shkobba125.rhcloud.com/
http://tickets-shkobba125.rhcloud.com/server.js
```

Is this a security issue?
How can i protect my server?

**UPDATE**

Here my middle-wares:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Here my project structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is to change the directory used in the `express.static()` middleware if you're using that. Typically there is a `public` or similarly-named directory that you would create that holds *only* your public assets.

Remove the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));`, this is what is allowing your code to be public.

Comment: Thanks, i'll test it, but i remember i added this to have a relative path to my other js files.. it's a big change in my project.

Comment: If your other (public) js files are outside of `./public`, then you should move them in there.

Comment: my public folder is intended to contain angular js files only. i'll seek for a solution

Comment: I added my project's structure, check it.